# Does resilient channel change the orientation that drywall is mounted?

Tags: drywall

I'm contemplating installing resilient channel and in the ceiling, my understanding is that drywall is hung perpendicular to the floor joists above. When resilient channel is installed, it runs perpendicular too, so then does the drywall get re-oriented to be perpendicular to the channel (and thus parallel to the joists)?

This video: https://youtu.be/-IfYuNnRLgU?t=3m35s

Suggests that the drywall is still run oriented the way it would be if it were just hung to the joists, so it runs down the channel, but I feel like I read somewhere that it's supposed to be run crossing the channel. This would actually be a benefit for me, because in that ("new") orientation, single sheets would fit across the room.

When looking at installation instructions for the channel, the "example" pictures conveniently include a square piece of drywall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sound studios where I work, we've had several rooms added using RC for acoustic dampening. The drywall is hung in the same orientation as the wall studs, but the pattern for screws holding the drywall is done differently to attach to the RC channel. I'll include an image showing the method I am most familiar with:

[image: RC Channel in sound dampening applications]

Answer (score 0):

You should always 'try' to install drywall perpendicular to the support. So you are right, it should be perpendicular to the RC, which will be parallel to the joists. With that said, if it makes more sense to run it perpendicular to the RC then it really isn't a bit deal to do so.

You can also run the RC with the joists too.